# Pairing type argument and argument sub-type argument in scala

Tags: scala, generic-type-argument

I have trouble doing an implementation that I found would solve my issue in a smart way: I want to have several implementations of some "converter" to different output types, but all implementation share some Schema definition.

It's quite difficult to explain with the word alone, so here is a sample code:

```
sealed trait Schema[+A]

object Schema{
  // Schema definition
  object IntSchema extends Schema[Int]
  // ...
  case class SeqSchema[B](bSchema: Schema[B]) extends Schema[Seq[B]]
  // ...
  case class MappedSchema[A,B](aToB: A => B, bSchema: Schema[B]) extends Schema[A]
  // ...

  // base implementations of conversion to "Dst"
  trait Dst // some output type, used below
  def convertIntToDst(i: Int): Dst = ???
  def convertSeqToDst[A](s: Seq[A]): Dst = ???
  // ...


  // *** here is what I want to do: ***
  // combine base conversion using schema
  def convertToDst[A](a: A, schema: Schema[A]): Dst = schema match {

    case IntSchema =>
      convertIntToDst(a.asInstanceOf[Int]) // (1) asInstanceOf :(

    case s: SeqSchema[_] =>
      convertSeqToDst(a.asInstanceOf[Seq[_]].map{ ai => // (2)
        convertToDst(ai, s.bSchema) // (3)
      })

    case s: MappedSchema[_,_] =>
      convertToDst(s.aToB(a), s.bSchema) // (4) fails to compile!!
  }

  // Would want to implement some conversion to other types, still using schema 
}
```

As you can see, I have trouble "pairing" the type `A` of the first argument of `converterToDst` to the type-argument of the `schema` argument. However, I think it should be safe from the method definition that both can be used together.
The error I get is

```
[...] type mismatch;
[error]  found   : a.type (with underlying type A)
[error]  required: _
    convertToDst(s.aToB(a), s.bSchema)
```

So I have two questions:

1. how can I make the case (4) compile?
2. Not the most important, but is there a way to not cast `a` on lines marked (1) and (2) ?

I think for the first question, but still using asInstanceOf, I could work something out if I could name the type-argument inside the match-case, such as `case s: MappedSchema[A,B] =>`. But this looks not to be possible (and maybe a bad idea due to type-erasure)

Note also that, after finding this issue, I found that it is strange that the case (3) compiles: (from IntelliJ) `ai` is `Any` and `c.bSchema` is `Schema[B]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name type parameters in patterns:

```
case s: SeqSchema[a1] =>
  convertSeqToDst(a.asInstanceOf[Seq[a1]].map{ ai => // (2)
    convertToDst(ai, s.bSchema) // (3)
  })

case s: MappedSchema[a1,b1] =>
  convertToDst(s.aToB(a.asInstanceOf[a1]), s.bSchema) // (4)
```

> I found that it is strange that the case (3) compiles: (from intellij) ai is Any and c.bSchema is Schema[B].

Because you declared `Schema` as covariant (`[+A]`), a `Schema[B]` is also a `Schema[Any]`, whatever `B` is.

Comment: I think that's the best solution for me, but I cannot test it before I get home. Do you think there could be trouble w.r.t type-erasure ? Basically, at runtime this sub types are not known.

Comment: @Juh_ There shouldn't be.

Comment: @Juh_ Also see the edit for your question on case (3) compiling.

Comment: Tx for this explanation on case (3). I made Schema covariant by default and it was just wrong... I should have known better: never do anything just in case, especially thoughtlessly

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be more type-safe and extensible to use **typeclasses**.

Here is a rewrite of your code using such approach, let me know if you have any problems adapting this to your real use case.

```
trait Dst

sealed trait Schema[A] {
  def convertToDst(input: A): Dst

  final def contraMap[B](bToA: B => A): Schema[B] = new Schema[B] {
    override final def convertToDst(input: B): Dst =
      this.convertToDst(input = bToA(input))
  }
}

object Schema {
  final implicit val IntSchema: Schema[Int] =
    new Schema[Int] {
      override final def convertToDst(input: Int): Dst =
        ???
    }

  implicit def listSchema[A](implicit aSchema: Schema[A]): Schema[List[A]] =
    new Schema[List[A]] {
      override final def convertToDst(input: List[A]): Dst =
        ???
    }

  def convertToDst[A](a: A)(implicit schema: Schema[A]): Dst =
    schema.convertToDst(input = a)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be so much about typeclasses, but rather about the good ol' OOP-esque `def convertToDst(input: A): Dst`, with a hard-coded type `Dst` inside of the `Schema[A]` definition...?

Comment: Yep, my point is to split schema and conversion. Because each time I want to add a new type of output (Dst) I will have to change all schema classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197127/discussion-between-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez-and-juh).

Answer (score 1):

You could help compiler infer types by fixing the first type parameter to `A`:

```
 case s: MappedSchema[A, _] =>
      convertToDst(s.aToB(a), s.bSchema)
```

Works on [Scala 2.13](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/9nH3mL7XSIambG8sJRCChg) and 2.12.

Comment: I actually didn't try to compile it and stopped because intellij underlined it red. Maybe I just need to update it and the scala plugin...

Comment: Just to be clear, when we add the arg-type `A`, scalac understand that `MappedSchema[A, _]` is mandatory because it is in a match-case on a `Schema[A]`? It doesn't add some code to assert &| cast it?

Comment: Sometimes IntelliJ shows red squiggly lines for valid code. Can you try to run it with `sbt compile` or even with IntelliJ's green play button to check if this compiles in your environment?

Comment: I am not in front of my computer where I work on this topic. But it works in your link to scastie, so I trust the result.

Comment: Problem with your code was, that compiler couldn't infer correct type for the first type parameter (as I checked in the console it was Nothing). Fixing type to A doesn't add any additional check, it just helps compiler figure out, that first type of `MappedSchema` is really `A` from Schema. This case of pattern matching would match on runtime `MappedSchema` without regard to type parameters, but it compiler wouldn't allow putting wrong types. So if you somehow managed to pass `MappedSchema` with wrong type parameters to `convertToDst` it will just fail with `ClassCastException`.

Comment: The Schema is a sealed trait made to not do it wrong. So if it compile, then the Schema should match at runtime. Maybe there are ways to cheat, but that would be on purpose and I only care to protect against mistake.

Comment: You can "cheat" by using `asInstanceOf` and  "trick" compiler to belive `MappedSchema[Int, String]` is for example `MappedSchema[Double, Boolea]` and it this case it will fail on runtime. If you don't do any unsafe casts, then the compiler would catch all errors.